# MDX query order issue

Tags: sql-server-2005, mdx

I have two dimension field say [Custom Date] which have data like 'September 2009' and [Custom Date With Formart] which have data like 'Sep-09'.

I am applying order function to arrange it  as shown below.

```
Order(BottomCount(
{[CUBE].[Custom Date].[Custom Date].ALLMEMBERS},  12),
[CUBE].[Custom Date].[Custom Date].[], DESC)
ON COLUMNS,
```

It arranges my dates as 'September 2009','October 2009'....,'January 2010','February 2010'.

```
Order(
{[CUBE].[Custom Date With Formart].[Custom Date With Formart].ALLMEMBERS},
[CUBE].[Custom Date].[Custom Date].[], DESC)
ON COLUMNS,
```

Output for above is like 'Jan-10','Feb-10',....,'Sep-09','Oct-09'.

What i want is to display [Custom Date With Formart] on axis and sort it using [Custom Date].

Let me  know your comments.

---

Thanks to all of you. I resolved my issue by following this [link](http://www.setfocus.com/technicalarticles/kgoff/buildingolapdatedimensions.aspx).

Comment: Any solutions please.!!!

Comment: What's the current output? What's your expected output?

Comment: Current out put is like Output for above is like 'Jan-10','Feb-10',....,'Sep-09','Oct-09'. But it's not in ascending order. It should be 'Sep-09,'Oct09'....,'Jan-10','Feb-10'

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to really understand your issue. Why do you need any specific ordering to get what seems to be 
the natural ordering of a time dimension. In any case, it might be that you need to use the BDESC option instead of DESC (see documentation [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Order.html)).

Comment: I tried using ASC,DESC,BASC and BDESC nothing works. I think [Custom Date With Formart] is my custom date format and shows like 'jan-10' that's why it's not sorting this things

Comment: what is : Order( ...,  [CUBE].[Custom Date].[Custom Date].[ ], DESC) I mean what does [ ] means ? If you want to sort by name, how about using [Custom Date].currentMember.name ?

Comment: Hi Marc, as per my knowledge while you are using order function first param is the thing you want to display, second param is the thing on which you want to sort out first param and third defines ASC or DESC. While giving Second param If I use [Cube].[Custom Date].[Custom Date] it shows error, that's the reason I need put put '[]'. Will try your suggestion and let you know result

Comment: The third parameter has to be a value that can be calculated at run time within the context of the current cell. So just mentioning the[Custom Date] dimension won't identify a tuple (that has a value for the currentmember). Sorry, I can't explain this very well, the whole idea of tuples is difficult...

Comment: I see... perhaps using Properties( KEY, TYPES) to get the underlying data that could be ordered.

Comment: @Marc: I tried using [CUBE].[Custom Date].[Custom Date].CurrentMember.Key but no luck :(.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a string to sort on, and converting it to a date, if you can cope with VBA:

```
ORDER(whatever, CDate("01-" + [my dimension].currentMember.caption), BDESC)
```

That code may not run as it is, but what I'm trying to suggest is that you take the string of your member name "Sep 10" and turn it into a string with a full date in (first of the month), which can then be converted into a date, and used to sort on.